# OS X suddenly unable to connect to Windows share

Tags: windows-server-2008, mac-osx, file-sharing, server-message-block

I have a network share to a Windows Server 2008 file server, that is used to view all media files on every computer at home. I've been able to access this share on OS X (10.6.2) for a year now, without problems.

This morning, however, I was unable to connect via OS X. I tried rebooting, and connecting to it's ip instead of the computer name, to no avail. A friend recommended deleting the .DS_Store files on the share as it might cause problems if this file is corrupted, but this didn't help either.

I can ping and RDP to the server. I can also connect to shares on all other computers except the file server.

I'm at a loss for what's caused this, and how I can fix it. I've haven't touched any settings on OSX or the file server in months, so that can't be it either.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not worthy of an answer, but look at antivirus and share settings on the Windows box.

Comment: The share isn't the issue. I can access the share from everywhere except the OS X client. Similarly, I can mount shares from any computer except the server in question. It's worked fine for a year.

Comment: What error does it give you? -36? Does anything appear in the logs `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`?

Comment: The 'Connection failed' error, the same error you'd get if you try to connect to a non existant server. I just checked the logs, nothing shows up.

Comment: I did find the following error when OS X decided to unmount the share 
Sender[PID]: KernelEventAgent[35]
Message: tid 00000000 type 'smbfs', mounted on 'Volumes/Steven-Server', from '//Steven@Steven-Server/D', dead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a reboot of the Windows Server as well as another reboot of OS X managed to do the trick.

I'm baffled as to what could've caused this. I could access the share from other computers just fine, so my rebooting the server was more an act of desperation than logic.